# How to implement a material design table?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I'm trying to create a table of the following format:

```
day | car type | car number
```

The table contains 8 rows (1 for header and 7 more for 7 days). The user can click on the `car type` or `car number` and fill it. He can't edit `day`. I would like the table to support Material design but I could not understand if it's possible to achieve with [Data tables](https://material.io/components/data-tables/). How can I implement the table?

Comment: Currently, you cannot implement this in android it is still not available for android.. it's still under planning

Comment: @PraveenSP What could be a good UI/UX alternative for that?